# Auto record and save chrome developer tools profiling data on page load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling, developer-tools, autosave

Chrome developer tools has an option to Start/Stop Recording profiling data with respect to Memory,Paint,Screenshots,JS Profile on the Timeline tab. Once I refresh a page the recording begins automatically and stops when the page has loaded.

Is there a way to

> 1)Start this recording in the background automatically **without needing
>   to open developer tools in chrome/node-webkit window**. Maybe the
>   recording can be enabled via some Chrome API which can be called when
>   the application loads
>
> 2)Dump the recorded data into a log file (e.x. a json file) once the
>   recording is over.

Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer here in the link below. Thanks to @Paul Irish

https://github.com/paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling/blob/master/readme.md#timeline-recording-example

Comment: Hey, actually I have also been searching for programatically (kind of automatic) running Chrome performace tests (in DevTools). https://stackoverflow.com/q/45493391/4983840
Do you know any similar way to do in Firefox?