# Chrome Developer Tools[TimeLine] Calculating Aggregated Time from json trace file

Tags: javascript, json, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to calculate the aggregate time for each of the events from the trace file saved after TimeLine recording in Chrome Developer Tools. Or do there exist some Node style Chrome API's to dump only this info as opposed to the huge amount of info dumped by the Tracing.start API provided by **chrome-remote-interface**.

I could automate timeline based recording using the example provided on https://github.com/paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling and get the trace file in json format.But I need to extract/derive only specific information from it as shown below.

e.g.

```
3.01s Total

7.73ms Loading

49.45ms Scripting

120.07ms Rendering

3.76ms Painting

19.68ms Other

2.81s Idle
```

Answer (score 0):

Found something very close to what I was looking for in https://github.com/GoogleChrome/node-big-rig

Answer (score 0):

I found this in another similar question, provided by @Abbas. Just leaving this answer here in case it is useful for someone in the future.

**Answer**

- [StackOverflow: Auto record and save chrome developer tools profiling data on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145777/auto-record-and-save-chrome-developer-tools-profiling-data-on-page-load?rq=1)

**Useful links**

- [GitHub: paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling](https://github.com/paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling/blob/master/readme.md#timeline-recording-example)
- [GitHub: paulirish/devtools-timeline-model](https://github.com/paulirish/devtools-timeline-model)

The devtools-timeline-model module should provide much of the functionality that is expected.