# Is it possible to programatically start application Performance test in web browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I would like to programatically start few Performance tests (like the one in Chrome Developer Tools in the tab, where you can click record button or hit Ctrl + E to capture a new recording). I want to do some performance tests in my application (on few views/subpages - it is SPA). However as I need to do them on different devices (PC, mobile phone) - I want to ask few friends to do it on their machines. But they are not programmers, so I don't want to bother them with writing any code or messing with dev tools, I just would like to send them application project and JavaScript script file. The only thing they will do is run application and that script, which will cause a performance test to be started automatically.

I wonder if Chrome Extension API (or Firefox API) expose sobe methods, or if it can be done via NodeJS (with some additional modules/libs included) - like NodeJS can get access to opened programs on Windows and capture that browser is opened with application started and then fire some event, which will start performance measurements?

Or maybe it is possible just from Dev Tools?

It would be nice if that script could also automatically save test results to JSON (like when you click right mouse button after test is finished and there are options to save and load Profile file) on device disk.

Comment: If your friends don't want to be bothered to use the devtools, I doubt they would use a different chrome extension, start chrome with command line flags, or even install node (which afaik is not available for mobile devices anyway).

Comment: Do you just want to run some benchmarks, that could be written using a simple js framework, or do you need the profiling results from the devtools?

Comment: Browser extension would be good I think - just installing, do tests and remove plugin from browser. Are there plugins that can automatically run Performance test in browser?
I want to run test, which show me CPU and Memoery usage with call stack and function invoke timing - as it is in Performance tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Try using WebPageTest. If the application is not hosted yet, there is a private instance of the tool available. Though it does not provide a JSON file, it does provide a result URL which can be revisited at any point in time. Tool link :https://www.webpagetest.org/

Comment: Found pretty nice solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35150996/4983840